# Exclude page from history

Tags: c#, blazor, maui

Is there way of excluding a page from being registered to the history? If a user visited this page and then navigated to another and hits the 'previous page' button, then I want the user to end up 2 pages back and not on the previous page. I'm aware of how to do this with JS but I'd like to avoid JS if possible.

Comment: What were you using? `NavigationManager.NavigateTo` has the argument `replace` for this purpose. I don't know how this works with MAUI though.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine It worked, thanks! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NavigationManager.NavigateTo` has the argument `replace` for this purpose, set to `false` by default.

[Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.navigateto?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-components-navigationmanager-navigateto(system-string-system-boolean-system-boolean))